# Flymake: no buildfile (Makefile) found

Tags: compilation, java

Let's say that I have a `makefile` in `./` and a file `./package/myclass.java`. From `./`, `make` works just normally, but using flymake-mode in Emacs, I always get the error

```
Flymake: No buildfile (Makefile) found for </absolute/path/to/myclass.java>. Flymake will be switched OFF.
```

The flymake manual says something about a customizable variable called `flymake-buildfile-dirs`, but this variable actually doesn't exist. I tried `cd` to `./`, and to add `../` to `flymake-master-file-dirs`, which didn't help either.

The strange thing is that on my Macbook, this works with the same configuration, while on my Debian GNU/Linux Desktop, it doesn't. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Flycheck has no Java support.

Comment: He's using flymake.

Comment: "He" is the poster himself answering a deleted comment stating that I should use flycheck instead.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out what was wrong. I simply re-wrote the makefile, which was initially written on my Macbook, on a different Computer. Flymake is now working correctly. I guess there was a problem with the character encoding.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I renamed it from `makefile` to `Makefile`. I tried renaming it back and the same error message came up. So I reverted it again to `Makefile` and flymake works. Very strange.

Comment: It has nothing to do with character encoding.  It's the renaming of the file that fixed Flymake, because Flymake explicitly only looks for `Makefile`, not for `makefile` or other names (e.g. `GNUmakefile`).  This is even mentioned in the commentary of `flymake.el`, right at the top.  See Emacs bug [18682](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=18682)